# List missing files in a directory and delete any extra

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm trying to work out how to compare files in a directory to a list of approved files. I would like to display the missing files and also delete any extra.

My code -

```
String[] approvedFiles = {"AAA.enc","LCQ.enc","MZXA.enc", "BBB.enc"};
    File folder = new File("test/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        //if (How to compare here?)
            System.err.println("File " + approvedFiles[i] + " missing.");
    }
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: You should make `approvedFiles` a `List<String>` so you can use `contains()` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach is to convert your approved file array and current file array to sets, and then subtract them.

I first create a map which relates string names of the files you have in hand with their actual corresponding `File` objects.  Subtracting the key set of this map from the `approvedFilesSet` yields the extra files.  The map comes in handy should you need to also delete these files, as the original `File` object can be gotten from a lookup.

```
String[] approvedFiles = {"AAA.enc","LCQ.enc","MZXA.enc", "BBB.enc"};
Set<String> approvedFilesSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(approvedFiles));
File folder = new File("test/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

Map<String, File> haveFilesMap = new HashMap<>();
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        haveFilesMap.put(file.getName(), file);
    }
}

// subtract the have files from the approved files
approvedFilesSet.removeAll(haveFilesMap.keySet());

for (String file : approvedFilesSet) {
    System.err.println("File " + file + " missing.");

    // uncomment the following if you also want to delete these extra files
    /*
    try {
        Files.delete(haveFilesMap.get(file).toPath());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error deleting file " + file);
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: How is that deleting the extra files ?

Comment: Is that extra map really required ? Can we use something simpler as `listOfFiles.forEach(file -> { if (!approvedFilesSet.remove(file)) { // Delete the extra file } });`

Comment: Ah...that assumes you are using Java 8.  Actually, you should post a Java 8 solution if it looks a lot simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much, the line `Files.delete(haveFilesMap.get(file).getPath());` seems to produces the error `The method delete(Path) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (String)` Any way to resolve this?

Comment: @Nick Try using `Files.delete(haveFilesMap.get(file).toPath());`

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop through the files in the folder you are comparing to and for each file ,see if it's in the approvedFiles list. If it is, do nothing (or print "found file". If it's not found, print "unknown file". Once you verify that works properly, you can change it to delete the unknown file

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the data structure for `approvedFiles` to be a `Set` and then use `remove` operation. E.g.

```
Set<String> approvedFiles = new HashSet<String({"AAA.enc","LCQ.enc","MZXA.enc", "BBB.enc"});
File folder = new File("test/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        approvedFiles.remove(listOfFiles[i].getName());
}
for (String missingFile : approvedFiles) {
   System.out.println("File " + missingFile + " is missing");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking cue from Tim's answer, I think this will get you the missing files and delete the extra ones. This answer uses Java 8 foreach loop

```
String[] approvedFiles = {"AAA.enc","LCQ.enc","MZXA.enc", "BBB.enc"};
Set<String> approvedFilesSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(approvedFiles));
File folder = new File("test/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

listOfFiles.forEach(file -> {
    if (!approvedFilesSet.remove(file)) {
        // Delete the extra file
        try {
            Files.delete(file);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error deleting file "+ file);
        }
    }
});

System.out.println("Missing Files: "+ approvedFilesSet);
```